# customize binding request parameters and fileds inside the accepted to controller method bean in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-initbinders

I have the following class:

```
public class MyDTO { 
       @NotEmpty      
       private String isKiosk;
       ...
}
```

and following url:

```
http://localhost:1234/mvc/controllerUrl?isKiosk=false
```

and following controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = APPLICATION_JSON)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<List<?>> getRequestSupportKludge(@Valid final MyDTO myDTO, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    ...
}
```

When I stop in debug  at getRequestSupportKludge method I see that myDTO.isKiosk equals null.

I cannot change the request url.

Where can I configure mapping for my request parameter ?

Comment: You need to use `@PathVariable`? You are passing single field, but expecting an object in the controller.
`@PathVariable("isKiosk") boolean isKiosk`

Comment: @Pramod Karandikar Actually I have more than 1 field. it is simplified example

Comment: From my experience, Spring 3.2 should be able to map the request parameters to java bean; however just a guess, is it because `isKiosk` is declared as `String` and not `boolean`?

Comment: Yes, I know it. My question about customizing this mechanism

Comment: Can you try adding the model attribute annotation: @Valid @ModelAttribute("mydto") MyDTO myDTO and see if its not null now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is working after adding following binder:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, "isKiosk", new PropertyEditorSupport() {
        public void setAsText(String name) {
            setValue(name);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @QueryParam to fetch the value in controller. What is binding isKiosk to myDTO? Nothing when you are requesting the URL like above. If you are using some view technology and form to submit data then it is important to bind the form variables to the object.

The other way is you can expose myDTO as a ModelAttribute and use

```
public xxxx controllerMethod(@ModelAttribute("myDTO") MyDTO myDTO, ...) {}
```